# React-Rails: How to render a component with a ref?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

At the moment I render my component inside a .erb file like this:

```
<%= react_component('Counter', number: @counter) %>
```

This component has a function that uses `promised-xhr`:

```
push: function(operation) {

    if(operation) {
      new_number = this.state.number +1;
    } else {
      new_number = this.state.number -1;
    }

 // This call works.
 // this.setState({number: new_number})

     XHR.post("/update", {
      data: {
        count: new_number
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
   // XHR.post is successful, so I can log the response.
      console.log(response.body.number);
   // But setState does not work because of 'this'
      this.setState({number: reponse.body.number})
    })

}
```

`this.setState({number: response.body.number)}` does not work because `this` is no longer the component. I am planning to use `React.findDOMNode(this.refs.myComponent)` to find my component and trigger the new state.

However, I can't figure how to use the `react_component` to assign a ref to my Counter component.

Comment: have you tried using `.bind(this)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about memoizing `this`, then using a local variable inside the callback?

```
push: function(operation) {
  // ... 
  // Store `this` as local variable `_this`:
  var _this = this 

  XHR.post("/update", {/*...*/})
    .then(function(response) {
    // use local variable `_this`, which still refers to the component:
      _this.setState({number: reponse.body.number
    })
}
```

As a side note, `ref` might not help. After calling `getDOMNode`, you'd have a DOM node (browser built-in), not a React component.

Comment: You are right. Promises are not good for what I am trying to do, old style callbacks neither. I am left wondering how to implement a component that changes state after receiving data from a request.

Comment: Use the `setState` function in the request handler, as shown above. Assign the component to `_this` (a local variable) so that can reference it from the request handler.